# How to hide the sidebar using Sphinx RTD theme when making htmlhelp

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Is it possible to hide the sidebar when using `Sphinx` with the `ReadTheDocs` theme?

Extending the question a bit more, can I have it include the sidebar when issuing a command:

> $ make html

and not include it issuing a command:

> $ make htmlhelp

without altering code? Maybe add something in the layout.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is poor form to ask two questions in one post.  Next time, create a separate question.

For your first question, I am not sure what the option `collapse_navigation` actually does, but its name implies that it does what you seek.  The default value is `False`, so toggle it to `True` and see what happens.  See other [Read the Docs theme configuration options](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme#configuration).

For your second question, there are at least two methods.

You can use the `-D` option of [`sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html#options) and override settings in your `conf.py`.

You can have multiple `conf.py` files (named as you see fit), and use the `-c` option to select the appropriate file for the output you want.

Comment: thanks Steve however collapse_navigation adds/removes the expand/collapse icon on the sidebar TOC at the top level, not what I'm after, appreciate the answer though.

Comment: Bummer. In that case, you can create a new configuration option to show/hide the sidebar, and edit your theme templates accordingly. I'd point you to Sphinx and Jinja2 documentation for how to add conditional logic.

Comment: Bummer indeed, ended up as you say, adding conditional logic around the navigation in the theme templates, stripping it out: {% if 'htmlhelp' not in builder %}

Answer (score 10):

In the `alabaster` theme, I was able to remove the TOC/sidebar by adding the following to my `conf.py` file:

```
html_theme_options = {
    # Disable showing the sidebar. Defaults to 'false'
    'nosidebar': True,
}
```

I tested this in the `sphinx_rtd_theme` and it did not work. However, I add this as an answer here as it might be helpful for others trying to remove the sidebar in *other themes* (as was the case for me).

Answer (score 2):

For building matlab documentation (which I believe is similar to HTMLHelp), I found that it is possible to hide the side-bar using a additional CSS:

```css
.wy-nav-side {
  display: none;
}

.wy-nav-content-wrap {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Then in the `conf.py` file I added the CSS file:

```py
html_static_path = ['_static']

html_css_files = [
    'css/matlabdoc.css',
]
```

This doesn't remove the side-bar, but at least it hides it.  Might help.

Looking through the RTD theme, it might also be possible to remove the side-bar
by changing the `search.html` and `localtoc.html` default files in `conf.py`
by setting them with `html_sidebars = {}`.

Comment: in modern sphinx, custom css is added like this:
[code]
# Custom css
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('theme_overrides.css')
[code]